# Rails association with errors is not invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I found this strange case with adding errors to an ActiveRecord object instantiated from an association. This case works as expected:

```
payment = Payment.new
# #<Payment:0x00007f996c3b8848 ...>
payment.errors.add(:base, 'some message')
payment.valid?
# false
```

Yet, if I attempt to do the same thing with an object instantiated from the association, the error is not blocking the validation:

```
payment = Customer.payments.build
# #<Payment:0x00007f994d318538 ...>
payment.valid?
# true
payment.errors.add(:base, 'error')
# ["error"]
payment.errors
# #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007f8d2c00a5a8
 @base= #<Payment:0x00007f8d20dcb680 id: nil>,
 @details={:base=>[{:error=>"error"}]},
 @messages={:base=>["error"]}>
## Yet, agonizingly --
payment.valid?
# true
```

Anyone has any ideas about what I'm missing here?

Comment: `valid?` resets `errors`, what does `payment.errors` return after second `payment.valid?` call?

Comment: That is correct. It is the default behaviour for ActiveModel validations. My confusion is why the first case works (i.e. when the model is not instantiated from the association)

Comment: do payment.reload then check .valid?. I think you will get a false. It's probably just the payment instant is not updated.

Answer (score -2):

The difference between these cases is `payment.customer` attribute, which may be validated for presence (at least) and is in fact present in your second case (the one returning `true`) and is not present in the first case, hence you (probably) get validation error. Of course I'm not sure since I didn't see your model. But it have to be something like this.